# How to continue after exception occurred in C# switch

Tags: c#, loops, exception, switch-statement

how can i continue the loop after exception occured ?

```
    foreach (var oItem in List<Client>)
        switch (oItem.Name)
        {
         case "one":
         {
            break;
         }


         case "two":
         case "three":
         {
            break;
         }


        }

}
```

when in block case one throw an exception, i want to continue to block Two or another block depends on value of the loop.

is that possible ?

becasue each case reprenting download the data via FTP from each client, so when the data of client one is throw an exception, it not mean that the data of rest of client bad also.
At the end of the loop , i will output which data of client that had been downloaded and which one are bad

Thanks you in advance,
Stev

Comment: I think you want a `catch` block. Need more detail, what exception?

Comment: yes but i can not put the try and catch in the switch case

Comment: Catch the exception. But why? It's like asking "if I get my legs blown off, how do I continue walking anyway?". Except for very rare cases, prevent the exception from happening in the first place.

Comment: What sort of exceptions are you expecting?

Comment: @harold: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Pistorius ?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, well, he is exceptional

Answer (score 3):

Put the code that throws the exception in a try/catch block.

```
case "one":
{
    try
    {
        //Code that may break
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Deal with the exception
    }
    break;
 }
```

However you should really be finding out *why* it's throwing an exception, and make sure that you don't execute the code if you're in a situation that will cause an exception to occur.

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to by pass the exception in yout code like

**NOTE** : If possible log exception in seprate file so that you can get the info for what items you are getting exception

```
 foreach (var oItem in List<Client>)
{
   try
    {
            switch (oItem.Name)
            {
             case "one":
             {

             }
             break;

             case "two":
             case "three":
             {

             }
             break;

            }
   }
   catch(Exception ex){ // log exception }
}
```

Comment: @user609511 - When a `case` throws, there will be no fall through, correct. If you need that, you should rethink your design.

Comment: @user609511- this will continuew with the next input form the for loop..and one it enter in one case it will not go to other case ..that y switch case used

Comment: @user609511 failing to perform an action when Name="one" and instead continue like it's "two" makes no sense to me. I suspect a design-issue

Answer (score 0):

If you catch the exception inside the loop, the loop will continue

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var oItem in List<Client>)
{
   ret_val=call_switch(oItem.Name);
}
------------
private string call_switch(string val_str)
{
   string ret_val="";
    try
    {
           switch (oItem.Name)
            {
             case "one":
             {
               ret_val="valuee.. ";
             }
             break;

             case "two":
             case "three":
             {

             }
             break;

            }

   }
   catch(Exception ex){ //... }
   return ret_val;
}
```